# Postman : Error: Parse Error: Invalid header value char

Tags: http, postman

everyone. I'm trying to use postman for hitting our prod api, but I get some error:

[image]

[image]

I did not have that problem two days ago, and I have no idea what is happening. Anyone can advise ?

Comment: Curl might be a bit more resilient. Would give it a shot and see what weird character is in your header.

Answer (score 9):

It looks like a new Postman build is using a stricter header parsing, which is causing some issues for response headers that are not well formatted.

https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/8747

Answer (score 2):

It's probably related to **response** header. Try this request in your browser and if it works, look at the response headers in devtools/network to find an invalid character.

In my case request wasn't working in Postman for one specific id. When I looked into response in devtools, I found that there was a double quote inside a double-quoted string header value and I think it caused this error, but I may well be wrong here.

Anyway, try this exact GET request in browser and see if it works there.

Answer (score 2):

Turning on the "Send no-cache Header" option resolved this for me:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when I was setting headers in golang using http like this:

```
w.Header().Set("‫‪X-Frame-Options‬‬", "‫‪Deny‬‬")
```

It worked fine in curl but not in postman and I didn't understand what was wrong. I also checked my headers using -v option in curl. Everything was correct. So I substitute Postman with Insomnia and it's working with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you give HttpStatusCode as NoContent, this issue comes up. If you change the HttpStatusCode, it will work.